# PhpStorm will not use 2 spaces for indents

Tags: phpstorm

I'm sorry, I know this has been asked before, but the other answers are not doing anything for me.

PhpStorm keeps using 4 spaces for indents, and it is driving me mad.  The file is a .php file, and all the settings I know of are correctly set.  I have checked these things:

1.) Editor | Code Style | 'Detect and use existing file indents' is not checked (and the file uses 2 spaces anyway)

2.) Editor | Code Style | PHP | 'Tab size' & 'Indent' are set to 2 spaces

3.) I have restarted PhpStorm

4.) I have closed and reopened the file.

5.) My PhpStorm is the most recent version, 2016.3.2

6.) There is only one `.editorconfig` in the path of the file, and here are its contents:

```
# Drupal editor configuration normalization
# @see http://editorconfig.org/

# This is the top-most .editorconfig file; do not search in parent directories.
root = true

# All files.
[*]
end_of_line = LF
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[composer.json]
indent_size = 4
```

I have also tried removing the last two lines, just out of paranoia, and after restarting PhpStorm again, it did nothing.

Comment: 1) Will it use 4 spaces in ALL .php files or just certain ones? 2) What about other file types (JavaScript/HTML/etc)? 3) What about other projects? 4) What about brand new empty project? 5) How it will behave with EditorConfig plugin removed (it is not bundled by default with PhpStorm)? 6) How it will behave if you disable ALL 3rd party plugins (those that are not installed by default, even if they made by JetBrains) 7) Will it be any different if you choose "Default" code style and not some custom?

Comment: 8) More radical -- if you back up and delete all IDE config files (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) -- then launch it with no importing any settings (so you staring fresh) -- will it be any better?

Comment: Thank you, LazyOne, I tried your suggestions and it was not doing this for all PHP files, only ones that began with `#!/usr/bin/env drush` before the <?php tag (as Drush scripts sometimes do).  When I removed that and made <?php start out the file, closed/reopened the file, it works fine.  If you put it as an answer, I would accept it.  I haven't been able to find anything like this in PhpStorm's issue tracker.  I'm not sure if I should report this as a bug.

Comment: Better report it, especially if you can reproduce it in another project. As for answer -- it was just a list of suggestion to check from me and not more-or-less precise answer. Better compile all your steps/experience and put it as answer -- it will help other users in similar situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turn out it's a bug in PhpStorm:

"Tab size" value is ignored if php file isn't started with `<?php` i.e.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush
<?php
```

> For those who are interested here is a ticket on PhpStorm's Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34735 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Also for newer IDE versions, check if `.editorconfig` config-file exists (in any directory of directory-chain leading to your script-file), because Settings from said config-file have higher priority, and will overwrite your IDE settings.

Comment: 9/24/20 - Still not fixed