# PhpStorm - "configure indents" not doing anything

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to work on a website that uses PHP files with a mix of PHP templating and HTML markup in them. I set my editor preferences to make tabs be 2 spaces wide, but when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it still adds a 4-space-wide tab.

[image: Screenshot of my Preferences window]

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of my editor window]

Note: I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640204/phpstorm-will-not-use-2-spaces-for-indents) but it doesn't apply to me because all of my files start with `<?php` as their first line.

Comment: Are you sure the project is using the default settings? Check the project settings to see if they're overriding.

Comment: @Barmar Where can I change whether or not it's overriding?

Comment: @WaltGottlieb Will it work if you create a **brand new and empty project** and add such 1 file there? If not: 1) Please export your Code Style as XML format and share it 2) Please provide a sample file where this does not work (share it with #1) 3.1) Please provide the screenshot of the whole IDE window. 3.2) Locate that file in the Project View panel, invoke "View | Quick Documentation" for it. That's to check how the file is treated by the IDE.

Comment: In the Scheme menu at the top, see if there's an entry for the project.